# What will <div="container-fluid"> do in amp-story?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, containers, amp-html, amp-story

http://stackoverflow.com/questions//container-fluid-vs-container

https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-container-and-container-fluid-what-is-the-difference/

> The .container class is the fixed width container. That does not mean
>   it is not responsive. It is responsive; however, it is fixed based on
>   screen size. The screen sizes include:
>
> ```
> xs for extra small devices (used for less than 768 e.g smart phones, mobile etc.)
> sm for small screens (From 768 pixels and up e.g. tablets)
> md for the medium screen (>= 992 pixels. Desktops/Laptops)
> lg for large screens (>= 1200. Pixels e.g. large desktops)
> ```
>
> The container-fluid class will take the full width of the viewport. If
>   you use the container-fluid and resize the browser, you may notice the
>   content inside it will adjust with every pixel to take the full
>   available width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it will do nothing, as this is not a part of `amp-story`.

This class comes from Twitter Bootstrap, so I've added the `[twitter-bootstrap]` tag to your question.  You would need to inline the Bootstrap CSS and not use the Bootstrap components or JavaScript.  Since that would require inlining ~20kb of CSS, it would probably be more performant to write your own media queries.

Also, the way that `amp-story` handles responsiveness is likely not compatible with Bootstrap, since the `amp-story` desktop UI has multiple smaller "viewports" within the browser window, which Bootstrap would not understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063272/using-accelerated-mobile-pages-with-bootstrap