# Can we use Bootstrap for Desktop and amp for mobile on same website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, amp-html

I have fully responsive bootstrap website. I want to use amp for mobile version and bootstrap for the desktop. Is there any way to integrate both at the same time.

Comment: Of course, you could use different includes for each client. But you're not specifying what server technologies you're using, so I'm in the blind here regarding how to optimize templates/HTML/components/etc.

Comment: Currently using Wordpress, i didn't specify this because i want to know core structure so i can use this on other technologies like php and html

Comment: Use bootstrap.css but not bootstrap.js. several examples on the web.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked few times before, using the search tool was going to give you the answer you were looking for.

this question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063272/using-accelerated-mobile-pages-with-bootstrap) and if you use google you can go to this page [here](http://using%20bootstrap%20with%20amp%20site:stackoverflow.com) to see all related questions to your question.

Thanks

Comment: Yes i used that search tool but my question was slightly different as I want to use two different pages for two different platforms. All I want to know, is there any method that we create bootstrap file for Desktop and amp file for the mobile. If we can create them, how will it be integrated in the site.(Using a pre function or create something new ).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant integrate both at the same time. Because of the both have Bootstrap and amp have there owned tags and Amp doesn't support the third Party Links. You can check the Amp Limitations here [https://soundst.com/google-amps-limitations-css-javascript-html/][1]

Thanks